# How to check if an array contains entry that starts with a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a small PHP script that scans a directory and creates an array, using `scandir`.

Now, the directory i'm scanning cantains a lot of images, some of them related to the same product, and named this way:

> Test_product.jpg
>
> Test_product_2.jpg
>
> Test_product_3.jpg
>
> and so on..

now, i'm trying to check if the array (scandir) contains these names, but when i try to use the `preg_match` to match a regex saying "if the array entry starts with..." it doesn't seams to work.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
$imageFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/service/img';
$imageList = scandir($imageFolder, 1);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$image_filename = $row['image_filename'];

$pattern = '/^' . $image_filename . '/';
preg_match($pattern, $image_filename, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[0]);

if (in_array($matches, $imageList)) {
   $key = array_search($matches, $imageList);
   echo $key;
 } else {
   echo "not found";
 }
```

What i'd like to achieve is basically create the array, check if the array containsmultiple images starting all with `$image_filename` and print out the array key.

Thank you

Comment: Use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) instead of a loop.

Comment: Also use [`quotemeta`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quotemeta.php) to wrap your variable in the regular expression like this: 
`$pattern = '/^' . quotemeta($image_filename) . '/';` to prevent any of these characters  `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] ( $ )` in your filename from being interpreted as a regex control character.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with `preg_match`. You seem to be creating a pattern from a filename, then searching that filename for the pattern you've just created. i.e searching a filename for itself.

Comment: @HoboSapiens my tought was: I have $image_filename (for example "TEST"), but some of them could be something like ("TEST_2", "TEST_3") so the pattern was to try to find each array entries that just start with $image_filename, try, hopefully, to include even the one with the underscores. If this is not the right way to tackle this at all, could you please guys suggest me the best way to do it? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to solve this in this way:

```
    $imageFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/service/img';
    $imageList = scandir($imageFolder, 1);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $image_filename = $row['image_filename'];

   $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $image_filename);
   $pattern = '/^(' . quotemeta($withoutExt) . ').*$/';

   foreach ($imageList as $image) {
      if (preg_match($pattern, $image)) {
           if (in_array($image, $imageList)) {
             $key = array_search($image, $imageList);
             echo $key;
           } else {
             echo "not found";
           }
      }
    }
```

Thanks anyway for your help! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function preg_grep instead, it's made specifically for returning array elements;

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: OP appears to be operating row-by-row on data retrieved from a database, not an array. `preg_grep` won't work here.

Comment: Ahh yes, I didn't read the post properly, my apols. If required, you could populate an array from the $result, but that's not what was asked, so ignore my post

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this way using php `glob()` to get

```
$files = glob('TEST_*.jpg');
```